# What do the dollar sign and underscore doing in this react-native code?

Tags: react-native

I came across this piece of code (in a react-native project):

```
items.push({label: item._, value: item.$.value});
```

What do the underscore and the dollar sign mean here?

Comment: It might help to indicate what the type of `item` is. Is it a class from React? Normally though, `_` and `$` would simply be valid property names in JavaScript. You can create your own objects with properties such as this: `const obj = { $: 'Some value', _: 'Some other value' };`

Comment: @Knelis Thanks. But it doesn't look like what you have described. It seems the `item` is some string in json format.

Answer (score 1):

`._` is basically from a loadash library but in your case basically it might be accessing some values which might be stored in `_` variable.

and in `item.$.value`, item must be a object in which `$` would possibly be a key name which uses `.` to access some value from `value` which might actually have some values.